# How to represent a verbal compound statement correctly?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

In one of the problems for checking validity of a statement, i came across a compound statement.The compound statement is:

> "We will go for swimming only if it is sunny".

So the statements are:

> $P:$  "we will go for swimming" and $Q:$   "it is sunny".

According to me, the statement can be represented as $Q \to P$, but my teacher said it should be $P \to Q$.

And the reason she gave is that the statement $P$ comes before statement $Q$ in the compound statement.
What i think is that we must consider meaning of the compound statement so as to represent it correctly.
And  $P \to Q$ and $Q \to P$ are not same.

Am I correct?
What should be the correct represntation of the compound statement in the problem  and why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$P \rightarrow Q$ is the statement that "if $P$, then $Q$", or equivalently, "$P$ only if $Q$". The first one you probably know, so why is it equivalent to the second? If we look at the truth table for implication, then $P \rightarrow Q$ is true either when $Q$ is true or when $P$ is false, and false when $P$ is true and $Q$ is false. So saying "$P$ only if $Q$" is saying that "we only allow $P$ to be true under the condition that $Q$ is also true", because otherwise we would have $P$ true and $Q$ false, and the statement would then be false.

Your original statement says "We will go swimming only if it is sunny", or "$P$ only if $Q$", so this becomes $P \rightarrow Q$.

Comment: Very nice ellaboration!

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your teacher is correct.

> Let $P:$ *"we go swimming"* and $Q:$ *"it's a sunny day"*.

Being a sunny day doesn't imply for sure that we go swimming.  But in case we go swimming, then  it is certainly a sunny day.

That means if $P$ is satisfied, then $Q$ must be satisfied for sure, i.e.
"$P$ only if $Q$" is equivalent to the implication  $P\to Q$.

Comment: Thank you it is very valuable explaination for me.

Comment: You are welcome!